# How to specify allowed key/value combinations on object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am wondering what the best way is to specify allowed combinations of key/values on an object. Say if Object[name] = 'bana' -> Object[type] === 'fruit'.

I came up with the following:

```js
type Base = {
  weight?: number
  unit?: string
}

interface Item<P, K> extends Base {
  name: P
  type: K
}

type AllowedType =
  | Item<'bana', 'fruit'>
  | Item<'teddy bear', 'toy'>
  | ....
```

is there a way that is a little more concise?

Comment: What about this solution do you find lacking? It seems fairly concise to me and is completely type safe. Once `Item` is setup it's easy to create new type with only the interface name and the two values you want to pair up. It's hard to get more concise than that.

Comment: I guess I’d like to provide only tuples at the Ende and not having to specify Item over and over again. But maybe I am overthinking …

Comment: Something more like `Items<[['bana', 'fruit'], ['teddy bear', 'toy']]>`?

Comment: Would that lead to the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you have already is good.

But you could avoid the manual union of all the `Item` types by capturing the pair combinations in a single type, and instead using a mapped type to construct the union. Something like:

```
type AllowedPairs = {
  'bana': 'fruit',
  'teddy bear': 'toy'
}
```

Then you could rebuild your `AllowedType` using:

```
type AllowedType = {
    [K in keyof AllowedPairs]: {name: K, type: AllowedPairs[K]}
}[keyof AllowedPairs]
```

This will save a few keystrokes when adding new valid pairs although I find it somewhat less readable than your original. You can decide if that is an acceptable tradeoff.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. Yea on second thought I think you are right, the “safe-some-keystrokes” is actually a bit harder to read.